# Convert 2 dimensional array into single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to covert below array into single array.
This is the my array code as below:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] =>  
                [value] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [value] => 4
                [label] => 0.5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [value] => 5
                [label] => 0.6
            )

    )
```

**Want below result:**

```
    Array(
            '4' =>  '0.5',
            '5' =>  '0.6',
   );
```

Comment: Try this: 

$single_array = array();

foreach($array as $keys => $values){
   $single_array[$values['label']] = $values['value'];
}

Comment: `$result = array_column($originalArray, 'label', 'value');`

Comment: @Nirbhav Gupta: Thanks your answer works for me thanks, please add this in answer I will up vote for this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$single_array = array();

foreach($array as $keys => $values){ 
   $single_array[$values['label']] = $values['value'];
}
```

Use can use filter like not empty or null as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array(
    array('value' => '', 'label' => ''),
    array('value' => 4, 'label' => 0.5),
    array('value' => 5, 'label' => 0.6)
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item_array){
    if(!empty($item_array['value'])){
        $new_array[$item_array['value']] = $item_array['label'];
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of following functions :

[`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

[`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function, If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE ([see converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

**Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php


$array = array(
    array('value' => '', 'label' => ''),
    array('value' => 4, 'label' => 0.5),
    array('value' => 5, 'label' => 0.6)
);

/* make use of array_column and array_combine */
print_r( array_combine( array_column($array, 'value'), array_column($array, 'label') ) );

/* to remove empty elements use array_filter */
print_r( array_filter( array_combine( array_column($array, 'value'), array_column($array, 'label') ) ) );

?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [] => 
    [4] => 0.5
    [5] => 0.6
)
Array
(
    [4] => 0.5
    [5] => 0.6
)
```